# How to divide an array into two indexes in php

Tags: php, arrays

i am fetching time from mysql_db below is my code...

```
$sql="SELECT * from employee_timings where emp_timing_date='$date'";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
$array=array();
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    # code...
    $emp_starting_time=$result['emp_in_time'];

}
```

below is my table from which i am fetching the values...[image]
the issue is it gives me result in following format 11:00:0014:00:00
and when i echo this

```
 echo $emp_starting_time[0];
```

it outputs the first character of first time i.e 1 and second time i.e 1
what i want is that whenever i echo

```
    $emp_Starting_time[0]
```

it should display the whole 1st starting_time which is 11:00:00
kindly tell me how to achieve that

Comment: What format are these values stored in in your database?

Comment: can you show us the block of code in which this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give `$emp_starting_time` variable the value `$result['emp_in_time'];`. It contains the result you are looking for in a `string` format. When you write `echo $emp_starting_time[0];`, it returns you the fist charracter of this string. Try `echo $emp_starting_time;`

**UPDATE**

You can create an array outside of the loop and then push in it each value:

```
$array=array();
while ($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    # code...
    array_push($array, $result['emp_in_time']);
}
```

Comment: sir it displays both the values i.e 11:00:0014:00:00

Comment: @iqra if you placed the `echo` in the `while` loop, it will display `emp_in_time` column value for each row, so yes in your case `11:00:00` and `14:00:00`.

Comment: i want 11:00:00 whenever i echo $emp_starting_time[0];

Comment: You will get `11:00:00` for the **first** row, and `14:00:00` for the **second** row. What exactly do you want to achieve with this value?

Comment: should i convert this string to array first that is whenever i echo [0] then it should display me the whole 1st element of array

Comment: @iqra I updated my answer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @iqra you're welcome! Please upvote and mark my answer as correct to let others know your question is answered.

Comment: @Huothe i have another question